# Setting .env.php file on heroku app

Tags: php, git, laravel, heroku, environment-variables

I have a big old project that has an `.env.php` file with configs for many clients.
Each client (in my case, client is a repository) has an env file with his specifics configurations.
I have a centralized repository that push for all others 'clients projects'. I have a remote in git called "main" and a lot of others remotes with the names of clients.
Then I can not put the env file inside the centralized repository. I need one env for each client (remote in git).
On heroku, each client as an app. And of course, this remote git address (of heroku app) is the address of my clients.
Today, I am trying to migrating to heroku. And I faced with this question about the many `.env.php` files that I have to put in each clients.
What would be the best way to send this files in heroku?

Comment: What's in the client specific repos besides config information.

Comment: System that manage car companies.

Comment: Everything in all clients is equal. Except the `.env.php` file. That I need to have one for each client.

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach is to write a script that pulls from the repos you need: the master one and a client specific one.

The script copies all the files into a directory and initializes a throwaway git repository on your local file system, adding all the combined files.

Finally the script pushes the throwaway repo to heroku.

Comment: Hmmm.. Unfortunately each client has 170mb.. This every throwaway copy will take a lot of time. Is there another similar practice?

Comment: 170 mb is not very much. You still need to push that amount of files per client to heroku. Since each client it's an app.

Comment: Yes.. But every time that I do a change in any client app, all code will be copied to a throwaway git and then pushed to heroku?

Comment: Just when you want to deploy to heroku. Then you delete when you are done.